Jetpack compose: Provide TextStyle using dimension resource
In jetpack compose, the MaterialTheme doesn't quite fit our app so we want to use a similar approach, but customized to our needs.
We want to define a class similar to Typography that will contain our styles. And then provide this class downwards to the composables.
data class MyTypography(
    val myStyle1: TextStyle,
    val myStyle2: TextStyle,
)

@Composable
fun MyTypography(): MyTypography {
    return MyTypography(
        myStyle1 = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = dimensionResource(R.dimen.style1_text_size).value.sp),
        myStyle2 = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = dimensionResource(R.dimen.style2_text_size).value.sp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    CompositionLocalProvider() { 
        // Provide MyTypography, how?
        
        Text(text = "foo", style = MyTypography.current.myStyle1)
    }
}

Our problem is that, in order to use dimensionResource(), we must be inside a @Composable context, hence the wrapping of the MyTypography class inside a @Composable MyTypography().
But then we cannot use the MyTypography() from within a CompositionLocalProvider.
We might be completely wrong in the approach here, and a better one might exist. The core problem is: How to use dimensionResources in TextStyles.

I don't know if this will answer your needs, but you can extend MaterialTheme. I did there with space:
@Immutable
data class YourNameSpacing(
val space2: Dp = 2.dp
)

internal val LocalSpacing = compositionLocalOf { YourNameSpacing() }

val MaterialTheme.yourNameSpace: YourNameSpacing
@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
get() = LocalSpacing.current

Then you can freely use it in Composable
modifier = Modifier.padding(top = MaterialTheme.yourNameSpace.space2)

you can read in the documentation about: Custom design systems in Compose

Use this code inside CompositionLocalProvider
Text(text = "foo", style = MyTypography().myStyle1)

instead of
Text(text = "foo", style = MyTypography.current.myStyle1)

